# Error: BrowserType.launch: Protocol error (Browser.getVersion): Browser closed when running codeceptjs docker image thru Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, codeceptjs

```
FROM codeceptjs/codeceptjs:latest
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/app
# Copy source code
COPY package.json /usr/app
COPY package-lock.json /usr/app
COPY . /usr/app
# Environment variables
ENV BASE_URL="Local Https URL"
ENV PARALLEL_RUN=false
ENV TAG=int
RUN rm -rf node_modules
RUN npm install
# Run tests
RUN npm run codeceptjs
```

I have written above docker file when I am pulling the latest docker image of Codeceptjs. When I am trying the Build the image then I am getting error when test execution starts.
Error is:

```
#12 6.636 [pid=286][err][286:286:1004/055308.159970:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1412)] Unable to open X display.
#12 6.636 ============================================================    
#12 6.636 Note: use DEBUG=pw:api environment variable to capture Playwright logs.
#12 6.636   browserType.launch: Protocol error (Browser.getVersion): Browser closed.
#12 6.636   ==================== Browser output: ====================     
#12 6.636   <launching> /ms-playwright/chromium-888113/chrome-linux/chrome --disable-background-networking --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-background
```

Comment: You don't usually need to run tests in your Dockerfile; if the test runner is trying to display results graphically, getting access to an X display is difficult in Docker in general and basically impossible in a Dockerfile.  Can you run your unit tests directly on the host, before you build an image?

Comment: Should I build image first and execute E2E tests from docker compose file. It needs to open Chromium browser (headless or header). I am trying to have local docker image of Codeceptjs and execute the tests from that image instead of downloading it every time